# Area chart with multicolour gradient

Tags: d3.js, charts, area

I'd like to build a chart similar to:
[Elevation over distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac2TC.png)

This chart shows 3 things: elevation (y) distance (x) and colour represents the gradient change. How can I replicate this using D3.js?

Comment: Did you check samples in [Example](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) website?

Answer (score 0):

You can check sample in the [samples](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) and pick something suitable for you depending on your requirement. But I'm suggesting something like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/431a331294d2b5ddd33f947cf4c81319) or [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062085) . First one does not give you color changing capability with it. You may need to read the documentation and find out. You can use the second one after reducing the width of bar to be very small. You may need to convert this to cater your data input method. I'm strongly suggesting you to go through the samples. As a help I'm posting few more samples you can customize.

[Area Gradient fill](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/4433087)

[Applying a colour gradient to an area fill in d3.js](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/applying-colour-gradient-to-area-fill.html)

Comment: I'd like to stick to area plot because it represents geographical data and when elevation is applied to the chart you can see the hills over the distance. Adding colour gradient helps to understand how steep the hill is going to be.

Comment: Ok. Still you can customize some samples in the [Samples](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) website. I will change the answer with new samples you can customize.

Comment: Now check my answer.

Comment: I looked through loads of examples before writing in here.
My last attempt looked like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SoWTD7nwB6Vv2fDocDyq


It doesn't' represent what original chart (please see the picture) was doing. The gradients are applied to the whole graph either horizontally or vertically and in my case, I just need to colour bits of area chart.

Comment: According to the picture you want thin vertical bars in a particular color. So why you don't try to customize a bar chart to have thinner bars.?